# Conditional Formatting on specific columns in pivot table v2 chart in Apache Superset

Tags: pivot-table, apache-superset

I wanted to know if there's any way I can apply conditional formatting(coloring) on specific columns in Pivot Table v2 chart in Apache Superset.

Tried:
In pivot table v2 chart when I try to apply formatting/coloring of data it applies on every column of the table in superset application.

Expected:
For example: In superset application I have a pivot table say with columns total orders, canceled orders, allocated orders and i want to apply coloring/formatting on total orders column only. So the total orders column data will only be displayed in colored format.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is possible in pivot tables (without customizing it in anyway, that is)

Since a pivot table shows the same metric (grouped on the basis of 2 or more columns), it might not make sense to show formatting on only one column.

If your pivot table is grouping by only two columns, you might try creating a table that shows the same data as your pivot table. And since you can write HTML in tables, you might be able to color only the column you need